# How to change the background color of <tr> to a color and then back to it's default color using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a `<table>` that is populated from a `mysql` database using `php`. The `<tr style="background-color:;">` is stored in the database for each record. I have made a small `Javascript` so that when the user selects (`onfocus`) or deselects (`onblur`) the `<input>`, the `<tr>` will change colors. I have it set so the color will be red when selected, but I want it to return to it's default color once deselected.

Here is a snippet of my code, located within a `while()` loop, where `$i` is incremented:

```
<tr id="row$i">
<td><input type="text" onfocus="attON('row$i')" onblur="attOFF('row$i')"></td>
</tr>
```

Here are my functions:

```
function attON(id)
    {
    var row = document.getElementById(id);
    row.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }

function attOFF(id)
    {
    var row = document.getElementById(id);
    row.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
```

As I'm sure you will guess, the `backgroundColor` does not change back to it's default value, it changes to the `<table>` color instead. I was thinking of maybe capturing the default color in `function attON(id)` and setting it to a global variable would be the answer, but I don't know how to do that. Obviously any other ideas are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: you mean to say that you have designed a page and you dont know the background color of table? Please dont mind but i am little confused

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question. The table is populated with records from a database and the row background color is stored in that database. The row color is different depending on the record type, so they are not the same color and can be in fact many different colors. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit this:

```
    function attOFF(id)
    {
        var row = document.getElementById(id);
        row.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
```

To this:

```
    function attOFF(id,realcolor)
    {
        var row = document.getElementById(id);
        row.style.backgroundColor = realcolor;
    }
```

Then change `attOFF('row$i')` to `attOFF('row$i','put here the PHP code to show the real color of the tr tag')`

Comment: You're a genius! And, I think, the only person who understood what I asked :) THANKS!!

Comment: @andrew okay, glad to hear it!

Comment: @GGG +1 for the demo. I'm not sure if it's easier or not, but it definitely works. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @AndrewFox no prob... here's a pure CSS solution just for fun -- http://jsfiddle.net/r2mkQ/2/

Comment: @GGG It's so nice to be around people that view coding as "fun" like I do :)

Comment: @AndrewFox haha, so true :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function attON(id)
{
    var row = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!row.getAttribute('data-originalColor')){
        var originalColor = row.style.backgroundColor;
        row.setAttribute('data-originalColor', originalColor);
    }
    row.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}

function attOFF(id)
{
    var row = document.getElementById(id);
    var originalColor = row.getAttribute('data-originalColor');
    row.style.backgroundColor = originalColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't try this answer as @gamehelp16 answer was less complicated "looking". Because I'm new to JavaScript I want to make sure I understand what I'm coding instead of just taking someone's answer without understanding it. I hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have different background highlight colors for each row, you should output these along with your markup as a `data-` attribute. Additionally, use `this` instead of adding functions with different `i` values:

```
<tr id="row$i">
    <td><input type="text" onfocus="attON(this);" onblur="attOFF(this);" data-color="$color"></td>
</tr>
```

Your functions would then be:

```
function attON(el) {
    el.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('data-color');
}

function attOFF(el) {
    el.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/yCNft/

Comment: +1 for the demo AND because I learned something new: `parentElement`

Answer (score 0):

I would combinate a CSS-Rule with the JS.

In CSS:

```
tr.activeRow {
  background: red !important;
}
```

This is the Javascript PART:

```
function attON(rowID) {
  // to be sure that there is always just on active row...
  var activeRows = document.getElementsByClassName('activeRow');
  for(a in activeRows) {
    activeRows[a].className = '';
  }
  // set classname to override the inline style
  document.getElementById(rowID).className="activeRow";
}

function attOFF(rowID) {
  // jus remove the classname
  document.getElementById(rowID).className="";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this won't work for what I'm doing.

Comment: @AndrewFox Sorry, I got the question wrong, I updated my answer. Still I would prefer a combination of a CSS-Rule and the JS-Functions. Like this I don't have to update JS, just to change a color value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind adding a hidden field in each tr that stores color from database.
Moreover, i have sent only id on events to functions and appended "row" with id in javascript.

```
<tr id="row$i">
    <td>
        <input type="text" onfocus="attON('$i')" onblur="attOFF('$i')">
        <input type="hidden" value="color from database" name="$iHC" id="$iHC">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript functions:

```
function attON(id){
    var row = document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}

function attOFF(id){
    var row = document.getElementById("row"+id);

    //fetch the value from HTML element and assign it to a javascript variable
    //remember to append "#" to value of color if you have not stored in database
    var color = document.getElementById(id+"HC").value();
    row.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```